# How to make the program loop until user input specific number

Tags: c

Basically, i need to write a program where the program ask the user to input specific number to get specific shapes. Like 1 for oval, 2 for rectangle and so on, the program needed to keep asking the user to input the numbers until the user enter  number 9 to end the program.
This the final working code in Turbo C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
clrscr();
 int x=0;

 while(x != 9)
 {
 printf ("Enter 1,2,3 and 4 for differeten shape and 9 to exit: ");
 scanf ("%d",&x);

 if (x == 1)
 {
     printf ( "*********\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*********\n");
 }

 else if (x == 2)
 {
     printf ("   ***   \n"
   " *     * \n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   "*       *\n"
   " *     * \n"
   "   ***   \n");
 }
 else if (x ==3)
  { printf( "    *    \n"
  "   ***   \n"
   "  *****  \n"
   "    *    \n"
   "    *    \n"
   "    *    \n"
   "    *    \n"
   "    *    \n"
   "    *    \n");
   }
   else if (x==4)
   {printf ("    *    \n"
   "   * *    \n"
   "  *   *   \n"
   " *     *  \n"
   "*       * \n"
   " *     *  \n"
   "  *   *   \n"
   "   * *    \n"
   "    *    \n");}

}
printf("The end\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Which language? 2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: In C or C++ use a do ... while loop. But as BobTFish says, pick your language first.

Comment: actually there are many ways to do this.. for example loop then an ifelse statement inside can handle..

Comment: C language,

What i have tried is makin a for loop

Comment: @user1852728 Ok, so don't tag `C#` and `C++`. "makin a for loop" is not in any way helpful. Post the code you have tried, and tell us **specifically** what does not work about it.

Comment: @user1852728 Well a for loop is the wrong choice. A for loop is normally used when you know *in advance* how many times you want to go round the loop. That's not the case here, use a do ... while loop instead. It's perfect for this situation.

Comment: @john I disagree. `for` is my go-to loop, even when it is not a "for `i` in [0,10)" style construct. I like having initialization, condition, and iteration all together. Can be much cleaner than a `while`, and I almost never use `do...while`.

Comment: @user1852728 Ok, now stop and think about this. For starters, `print shape` is not valid `C`, but more importantly, how do you expect to loop until the user inputs `9` when you don't even attempt to read any user input? If the question is "how do I read user input in `C`?", then ask that (and it will likely be closed and you will be directed to a book or tutorial, but still, ask the question you really mean).

Comment: @BoBTFish thats just the rough idea  of what im trying to do, not the code itself.
 Basically what im thinking is by doing a nested if else if conditional in a do while loop

Comment: Perhaps consider a [`switch` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main ()
{      
     int value=0;

     while(value != 9)
     {
         printf ("Enter your choice: ");
         scanf ("%d",&value);

         if (value == 1) 
         {    
             printf ("Oval");
         }

         else if (value == 2)
         {
             printf ("Rectangle");
         }       
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As this is `C`, that should be `int main (void)` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (although what you have written is of course supported basically everywhere).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BoBTFish but I am C# programmer. This is what I remembered I used to write while in school. In fact recalling scanf itself was a challenge. But thanks anyways. :)

Comment: The Switch condition would be a better choice though instead of if - else if construct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int input = 0;

while(1) {
    scanf("%d", &input);

    switch(input) {
        case 9:
            break;

        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you want to check if the user entered `9` *before* "doing your thing"?